# Dudas sobre Maven en Eclipse (pom.xml y autocompletado para la gestión de dependencias)

Tags: maven, dependencias

Tengo un par de problemas en Eclipse, a ver si alguien me puede echar un cable:

1. La primera es sobre la visualización del pom. Instalé un paquete en el Eclipse para Maven (el M2E Settings 2.0.4) y me dejó el pom con este formato:

[image: Imagen del pom]

Desinstalé el paquete pero me sigue apareciendo en ese formato, también probé Window -> Show perspective -> Reset perspective, y nada.

Estoy intentando que se vuelva a ver en la manera clásica (como en la captura de abajo), pero no soy capaz, ¿a alguien más le ha pasado?

[image: Pom clásico]

Mi segunda pregunta es sobre la búsqueda de dependencias, no me funciona, en el buscador de dependencias o cuadro de búsqueda, pongo dependencias para buscar y no me aperece ninguna, como adjunto en la pantalla de abajo, que sí funciona:

[image: Buscar dependencias]

¿Se os ocurre alguna solución?

Un saludo y muchas gracias